# iceprog - Can't find iCE FTDI USB device with Alchitry CU

Tags: fpga, yosys, icestorm

I'm trying to upload my build code to my alchitry-CU FPGA board threw apio using iceprog on windows.

```
apio upload
```

which then executes

```
iceprog -d i:0x0403:0x6010:0 hardware.bin
```

And the output is

```
init..
Can't find iCE FTDI USB device (device string i:0x0403:0x6010:0).
ABORT.
scons: *** [upload] Error 2
```

I have installed the libusbk driver and also tested uploading with the same cable on another pc with the standard drivers and the provided IDE Alchitry Labs in combination with iceCube2 but I really wanted to use the open source alternative instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the fix. The problem was that the Alchistry CU shows up as two different devices in Zodic when installing the drivers, one as Interface 0 and one as Interface 1 and I didn't see the other one and only installed the libUsbK driver on one of them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).